# Se ejecuta submit tras pulsar un botón de formulario

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

En un formulario web tengo un botón
`<button id='traspasar' name='traspasar'>Traspasar Dirección</button>`
que ejecuta el siguiente script.
El script rellena un campo dirección con el valor que hay en el campo domicilio y además rellena una lista con unos valores de ruta

```
$('#traspasar').click(function(e) {
    $('#direccion').val($('#domicilio').val())
    
    //obtener rutas en select
    direccion= $('#direccion').val();
    
    //valores del select de ruta_select en funcion de direccion

    url= "index.php?controller=aguasDatos&action=getRutas";
    if (direccion !='') {
        url=url+"&direccion="+direccion;
    }

    $.ajax({
      method: "get",
      url: url,
      data: {direccion:direccion},
      dataType: 'json',
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        $('#ruta_select').text('');
        $.each(data.data, function( key, value ) {
                $('#ruta_select')
                .append( $('<option>',{value: key}).text(value));
            });
        
      }).fail(function() {
          $('#respuesta').text(''); 
        $('#respuesta').append("<div class='aviso error'>"+'Ha ocurrido algún error'+"</div>"); 
            
       
   });
});
```

Una vez finalizada la ejecución del script, me ejecuta el submit del formulario y no sé por qué. ¿Alguien puede echarme una mano?
Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por omisión, una etiqueta `<button>` **es de tipo submit**. Por lo que tendrías que indicarle que es `type="button"` para evitar que lance el formulario. Tu botón quedaría así:

```
<button id='traspasar' type="button" name='traspasar'>Traspasar Dirección</button>
```

**Referencia:** [Atributos de etiqueta button](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#atributos)